# how to understand the curly braces here in these javascript codes?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I got such a piece of javascript code generated by **babel-preset-es2015** from ES6 syntax, it can run correctly, but i can't understand the '{}' here.please tell me, thx.

```
{
    var foo = function foo() {
        alert(3);
        return 1;
    };

    foo();
    {
        var _foo = function _foo() {
            alert(2);
            return 2;
        };

        _foo();
    }
}
```

according to the ES6 API, the curly braces here means a self-executing function:

```
{
    function foo () { alert(3);return 1 }
    foo() === 1
    {
        function foo () { alert(2) return 2 }
        foo() === 2
    }
    foo() === 1
}
```

if using ES5,it should be like:

```
//  only in ES5 with the help of block-scope emulating
//  function scopes and function expressions
(function () {
    var foo = function () { alert(3);return 1; }
    foo() === 1;
    (function () {
        var foo = function () { alert(2);return 2; }
        foo() === 2;
    })();
    foo() === 1;
})();
```

but,after compiled by **babel-preset-es2015**, it still use '{}' instead of an anonymous self-executing function.

so, i am confused about it, i never heard about this usage of curly braces.

Comment: Which curly braces are you confused about?

Comment: i'v improved my question.thx

Comment: @remus He means the ones wrapping the whole snippet, and the ones wrapping `_foo`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the curly braces are enclosing a **block**. In this case, they're **scoping** the two `foo` functions differently.

```
{
    function foo () { alert(3);return 1 }
    foo() === 1 // we get an alert(3) and it returns 1
    {
        function foo () { alert(2) return 2 }
        foo() === 2 // we get an alert(2) and it returns 2
    }
    foo() === 1 // we get an alert(3) and it returns 1
}
```

If, instead, the code was:

```
{
    function foo () { alert(3);return 1 }
    foo() === 1 // we get an alert(3) and it returns 1
    {
        // no definition of another foo function
        foo() === 2 // this evaluates to false; we still get an alert(3) and return 1
    }
    foo() === 1 // we get an alert(3) and it returns 1
}
```

For more information, you might want to research **blocks**, **scoping**, and **closures**.

Merry Christmas!